# How To enable/disable "Lock Screen" setting from Linux terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal, gentoo, lock

Please, do NOT say how to lock screen, i know how to do it.

How To **enable/disable** Lock Screen service from terminal? Looks it's using xflock4 for locking screen.

I can enable or disable it in Screensaver preferences, but want to do it with keyboard button. I don't need shell script, just with which command I can enable or disable it.

I Have Gentoo Linux, Xfce 4.16

Thank You!

[image]

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot give you a straight answer but might guide you to it.

Essentially you are looking for the place where Xfce stores its settings and then a way to change them (one setting actually, enable/disable screen lock) using commands, not clicking on the GUI settings.

Xfce uses `xconfd` for settings. `xfconf-query` command should help find the right setting and change it.

[xfconf](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/start)
[xfconf-query](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query)

Comment: Thank You!!! Working now. Followed guide: https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/xfconf-query I created commands: xfconf-query -c xfce4-screensaver -np '/lock/enabled' -s 'true'  and xfconf-query -c xfce4-screensaver -np '/lock/enabled' -s 'false'

Answer (score 0):

In linux, the locking of the screen is managed (hinted by the words found in the title bar of your window) by your particular installed `screensaver` and as such *typically* you should be able to enable it from the terminal using the following:

```bash
xscreensaver-command -activate
```

In gnome, the similar effect is - if I recall correctly - achieved using:

```bash
gnome-screensaver-command --activate
```

Comment: In my system its xfce4-screensaver-command --activate Thanks for reply, but its turns on screensaver, but I want **enable** or **disable** "Lock Screen" NOT screensaver it self.

Answer (score 0):

On my Xubuntu 20.04 (Ubuntu with Xfce as window manager), I simply invoke `xflock4` and the screen blanks (my screensaver preference) and prompts me to authenticate when I press a key or move the mouse.

Comment: Why again? I'm NOT asking how to turn it on, but HOW TO ENABLE AND DISABLE it as in picture, but in terminal.

Comment: I gave you the terminal command that locks the screen on my computer.  As I said, ON MY COMPUTER this happens to also engage the screensaver, but that's because of my computer's configuration, not because the command invokes the screensaver.  After the screen is locked, I can't get a terminal window to invoke a terminal command to unlock the screen without unlocking the screen via the on-screen prompts.  Was this not what you wanted when you asked how to enable and disable the screen lock via terminal commands where Xfce is present?